# Why didn't operations on a copy of a list also modify elements in the original list?

Tags: python, list, pointers, reference, copy

In Python everything should be represented with a pointer. Therefore, I expected the following code to modify the original list `a` as well, since I thought the list `copy` would contain all the original pointers contained in `a`:

```
import copy

a = ["a", "a"]

copy = copy.copy(a)
for (count, e) in enumerate(copy):
    copy[count] += "b"

print copy
print a
```

I expected to see `["ab", "ab"]`. Surprisingly, `a` still contains `["a", "a"]` only while `copy` indeed contains `["ab", "ab"]`. Using `copy = list(a)` doesn’t work either.

I thought this result would only happen if I wrote `copy = copy.deepcopy(a)`.

Where did I get wrong? What is the proper way of acquiring the references to all elements in a list and modifying them in a mirror list? Or is it just not possible in Python?

Comment: Strings are immutable?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: @chepner Beat you by 3 seconds :P

Comment: Yeah. You didn't modify the objects. You simply created new ones, and put them in the new list. Strings are immutable - they can't be modified.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I prefer to think I answered your question extremely fast :)

Comment: Doing `+=` for a string doesn't modify that string - it simply creates a new one.

Comment: Right, then my question is why didn't the original strings in `a` get replaced by the new ones. Shouldn't the pointers point to the same objects? That's the core of my question I think.

Comment: @JIXiang Read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: You can think of each element in the list as a separate "pointer" that points to an object.  When changing the contents of the list, you are changing what these pointers point to.

Comment: They are different pointers, because there are different objects. If you like memory address', say a had 1 and 2. Copy had 1 and 2, but then you changed it to 3 and 4, when you tried changing the strings. You allocated new strings, you didn't modify the old ones.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the link. That should help me clarify the issue. I didn't have a solid enough grounding in Python. It seems that the Python Tutorial really just contains the bare minimum of information needed to use Python and I should look for some more references before programming comfortably there.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused. The entire purpose of using `copy.copy` is to make a new list with no reference to the old one. If you do want to keep a reference, then don't copy it:

```
a = ["a", "a"]
copy = a
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually answers my question. So what is supposed to be the difference between `copy` and `deepcopy` in this case?

Comment: @JIXiang Copy will create a new list, but all the elements inside that list are the same. Deepcopy will try to re-create those elements as well.

Comment: @JIXiang: There will be no practical difference unless the elements in the list are mutable, which in this case they are not.

Comment: Incorrect. `deecopy` removed references entirely. `copy` keeps the references _inside_ the list. Take for example a list of lists: modifying a list inside of a list that's been copied will still modify the original list's internal list as well. There is very much a practical difference, and we're inherently teaching the wrong thing otherwise, for example if the user decided to eventually code Java one day and use char arrays instead of String. EDIT: Didn't see @Zizouz212's comment.

Comment: Also worth noting, the following also makes a copy of the list: `li = list(['a', 'b'])`